# AirPlay: redirect audio by showing the available devices popup

Tags: ios, audio, airplay

I'm trying to implement the same **AirPlay** button as the Music.app. The button displays a popup with a list of available devices which the user can select to reroute the audio.

[image: airplay-music-app]

While searching about my issue, I found out the [**`MPVolumeView`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview) but that's not what the Music.app is using. Even the Control Center is using that popup.

[image: airplay-control-center]

How can I present that popup in my app?

**UPDATE:**

I saw that same popup in AppStore apps as well, so it should be a Public API.

[image: sodes-app]

Comment: Are you looking for [`AVRoutePickerView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avroutepickerview)?

Comment: Oh, I think that's it. Thanks @Paulw11!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`AVRoutePickerView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avroutepickerview) which is available in iOS 11+ provides this interface.

**`AVRoutePicketView`** is like a `UIButton` and it works in the Simulator:

[image]

```
let routePickerView = AVRoutePickerView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
routePickerView.tintColor = .white
view.addSubview(routePickerView)
```

If your app supports older versions of iOS then you will need to check the version of iOS that your app is running on and use the older `MPVolumeView` if necessary (`MPVolumeView` doesn't work in the Simulator!).